# Messed up my sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I seem to have messed up the sudo apt update command in Terminal.

`sudo apt update`:

```
E: Invalid value set for option Signed-By regarding source https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public (not a fingerprint)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
E:
```

I'm just starting to figure out Ubuntu (complete beginner).

Can someone please help me understand what I've done and how I can fix this?

Comment: ```
asaraci@Saraci1:~$ cat /etc/apt/source.list
cat: /etc/apt/source.list: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the output but the output was blank

Comment: Use the GUI "Software &Updates" instead. The additional sources you added are at Other... tab. Remove the one mentioned in your error message.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using ?

Comment: I am using 22.10

Comment: @Nmath - I have update the question, the result does not change

Comment: @ChanganAuto - i have tried that as well, but it is not opening and am not able to remove the file mentioned in the error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add key for Plexmedia server.
You can do it by executing below command in terminal.

```
curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

You need to generate source list file which is messed up.

You need to edit `/etc/apt/source.list` file and place below content for Ubuntu 22.10 version. You can do it by executing below command in terminal.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list
```

Place below content in editor and save it.

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

After that you should able to run `sudo apt update` without any error.